# Filling in missing pandas dataframe (timeseries) data with last valid

Tags: pandas

Let's save I have two DataFrames of timeseries stock data.

How can I fill in NaN with the last valid value?

So,

```
2014-01-23 07:00:00.698708  428.75      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:19.783769  428.75      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:22.089900  429.00      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:22.089900  429.00      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:22.096339  429.00      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:15.991013     NaN  1283.75
2014-01-23 07:00:25.280246     NaN  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:31.746926     NaN  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:31.747813     NaN  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:50.055061     NaN  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:56.467059     NaN  1284.25
```

Should be:

```
2014-01-23 07:00:00.698708  428.75      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:19.783769  428.75      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:22.089900  429.00      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:22.089900  429.00      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:22.096339  429.00      NaN
2014-01-23 07:00:15.991013     429.00  1283.75
2014-01-23 07:00:25.280246     429.00  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:31.746926     429.00  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:31.747813     429.00  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:50.055061     429.00  1284.00
2014-01-23 07:00:56.467059     429.00  1284.25
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can simply use `df.ffill()`